# How can I pass a slice as a variadic input?

Tags: go

I have a function `func more(... t)`. I'm wondering if it's possible to use a slice to populate a list of arguments `...` .

I'm trying to solve the following program. Basically to mimic a normal shell which receives the command as a string.
 [Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) function requires a "list" of arguments and I don't see how I can convert a string into a such list

```
    import "os/exec"
    import "strings"
    func main(){
        plainCommand  := "echo hello world"
        sliceA := strings.Fields(plainCommand)
        cmd := exec.Command(sliceA)
    }
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Passing arguments to ... parameters](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)
>
> If f is variadic with final parameter type ...T, then within the
>   function the argument is equivalent to a parameter of type []T. At
>   each call of f, the argument passed to the final parameter is a new
>   slice of type []T whose successive elements are the actual arguments,
>   which all must be assignable to the type T. The length of the slice is
>   therefore the number of arguments bound to the final parameter and may
>   differ for each call site.

---

> [Package exec](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)
>
> [func Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)
>
> ```
> func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
> ```
>
> Command returns the Cmd struct to execute the named program with the
>   given arguments.
>
> The returned Cmd's Args field is constructed from the command name
>   followed by the elements of arg, so arg should not include the command
>   name itself. For example, Command("echo", "hello")

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    name := "echo"
    args := []string{"hello", "world"}
    cmd := exec.Command(name, args...)
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 23):

A list of command arguments can be retrieved from the [flag package `Args()` function](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Args). You can then pass this to a function using the variadic input style (`func(input...)`)

From [the Spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec):

> If f is variadic with final parameter type ...T, then within the function the argument is equivalent to a parameter of type []T. At each call of f, the argument passed to the final parameter is a new slice of type []T whose successive elements are the actual arguments, which all must be assignable to the type T.

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func echo(strings ...string) {
    for _, s := range strings {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    strings := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    echo(strings...) // Treat input to function as variadic
}
```

See [The Go spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) for more details.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Qv9c9hPuru)

Answer (score 8):

> [func Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)
>
> ```
> func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
> ```
>
> Command returns the Cmd struct to execute the named program with the given arguments.

So you have to extract the command which is found at `sliceA[0]` and then pass all the arguments with a variadic but removing the command `sliceA[1:]...`.

```
import "os/exec"
import "strings"
func main(){
    plainCommand  := "echo hello world"
    sliceA := strings.Fields(plainCommand)
    cmd := exec.Command(sliceA[0], sliceA[1:]...)
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution. Just for anyone else wondering - if you have a slice that is length 1 `slice[1:]...` does not fail, it is instead treated as `[]...`. Useful if you don't know the command that will be used ahead of time.