# Does golang sql Exec support variable arguments?

Tags: sql, go, variadic-functions

How can I pass a function's variadic arguments to a SQL.db Exec function?

This code

```golang
func dbExecOne(db *sql.DB, cmd string, args ...interface{}) error {
    if _, err := db.Exec(cmd, args); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("db execute[%s, %s] %q", cmd, args, err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Produces this error when called.  If this can't be done, is there an alternate way, perhaps using a lambda to capture the command and args?

```golang
dbExecOne(db, "insert into junk values($1, $2)", 99, "foo")

  db execute[insert into junk values($1, $2), [%!s(int=99) foo]]
  "sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface"
```

Comment: `db.Exec(cmd, args...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a slice as a variadic input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723955/how-can-i-pass-a-slice-as-a-variadic-input)

Answer (score 0):

You can always spread a slice's elements over variadic arguments with the `...` operator, like this:

```
db.Exec(cmd, args...)
```

For more info see [the language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)